# How to avoid exiting full screen when pressing an EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a login screen that I currently setup to be fullscreen (no action bar and status bar).

I'm using a `NoActionBar` theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then this is the code in my `MainActivity.java` file to hide the status bar:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    }
```

I got the snippet from the Android Developers documentation on hiding the status bar.

Everything looks great but once I tap on the EditText in the same activity, the status bar reappears as the soft keyboard is shown.

How can I keep the status bar from appearing when this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the fullscreen flag in the window, not in the decor view.

Use the following code inside `onCreate` to make your activity full screen:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```